# Checkbox state always false - HTML, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a check box in my html

```
<input type="checkbox" name"cleanse" id="id_cleanse value="cleanse">Cleanse Selected Data?
```

I also try and access the state of it to be sent back in a GET for the server

```
cleanse_state = $("#id_cleanse").is(':checked')
```

then

```
$.get("/proj/prij/",
            {
                cleanse_state: cleanse_state,
            },
            function(data){
                spacing()
            });
```

But on the server side whenever I access this, the state is always False - irrelevant of whether or not the check box is checked or not.

How can this be?

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typo in your question or actually in the code, but you're missing the closing quote on `id="id_cleanse`

Comment: have you  tried:  ``$("#id_cleanse")[0].checked``

Comment: thanks for the comment Eshan but j08691 spotted the error, pretty bad mistake - only using notepad to edit the script to hard to pick these things up, good spot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are not closing the `"` of Id attribute. And also you have omitted equal sign on your name attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cleanse" id="id_cleanse" value="cleanse"> Cleanse Selected Data?
```

Comment: If this is actually the case, which I noted in a comment above, then you should vote to close the question as off-topic as due to a typo, not farm rep from it.

Comment: @j08691 ohhhhh sorry about that, but I didn't know typo goes to off-topic.